# My cocoa application only runs if you run as admin in Lion 10.7.4?

Tags: cocoa, client, osx-lion, administrator

This problem only occurs on Lion (10.7.4) version when I try to open the application using non-Administrative login accounts. Although the application is developed and coded under non administrative login privileges. The application working on other systems for lower versions [till Lion 10.7.2]. Can anyone help me to know Why it is happening?

Comment: Is your application sandboxed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my application, I have not added the `core plot framework` properly. Now I corrected myself to overcome the problem.